# C#: Checking if a socket has a active connection to the server?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to find a legitamate wya to tell if the socket has a connection with the server. This becomes invalid if they haven't connected yet, or either the client or server has closed it.

This method is currently returning null before I ever connect to the server using this socket object. Can anyone explain to me why it does that, and how I can fix it?

```
private static bool IsConnected(Socket socket)
{
    return !(socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);
}
```

Comment: the first arg on socket.Poll is in microseconds, are you sure you want to use the value 1?

Comment: besides which, `socket.Poll` with `SelectRead` just asks "is there something to read?" - which is a **completely different question** to "is this socket alive?"

Answer (score 3):

The **only** way to know if a socket is valid is to send something and get something back. Every other way is a lie. `.Available` only tells you whether there is data in the current read-buffer. The status is ... at best unreliable. Sockets can die without the OS noticing. Sockets can be artificially spoofed as "alive" by network hardware - in an attempt to prevent temporary network blips (especially for wifi or mobile users) severing all their sockets; but sometimes that device never comes back, and *the device in the middle doesn't notice*. This means that even TCP-level broken-socket detection is *unreliable*.

So: send some kind of test message and get something back. That is the **only** way.