# How to determine when TcpClient connection is broken and reconnect

Tags: c#, sockets

EDIT: I understand the issue but need a code example to show how to solve it.

I would like for my client to reconnect automatically if it becomes disconnected but it appears `TcpClient.Connected` is not reliable for it. I've read that you need to send data for the class to change that flag. Is there a better way to handle to problem?

```
//Method to handle reading data from buffer and deserializing
public static async Task<Message> ReadMessageAsync(this TcpClient client)
{
    if (client.Connected && client.Available > 0)
    {
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        var data = new byte[client.Available];

        while (totalBytesRead < client.Available)
        {
            totalBytesRead += await client.GetStream().ReadAsync(data, 0, client.Available);
        }

        return BinarySerializer.DeserializeMessage(data) as Message;
    }

    return null;
}

public async Task Start()
{
    ConnectToServer();

    while (_isRunning)
    {
        // Reconnect to server if needed.
        if (!_tcpClient.Connected)
        {
            ConnectToServer();
        }

        // Wait for data
        var data = await _tcpClient.ReadMessageAsync();
            HandleData(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: there's [only one way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49695769/23354) to know if a socket is working...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test for a broken connection of TCPClient after being connected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650402/how-to-test-for-a-broken-connection-of-tcpclient-after-being-connected)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the quick response. I believe I understand the last I/O sets the flag just not sure of the best practice for handling the event? Catch the exception and call `Connect` again? Side-note seems like this class expects you to use exceptions for program-flow when that's not good practice?

Comment: Note that your code will burn your cpu, because if there is no data available in socket (common thing) it basically becomes while(true) loop.

Comment: Event will not always work.  The Event is caused by activity on the Ethernet interface.  Disconnecting the cable will cause a disconnect but will not trigger the event.  Neither will the server being shutdown cause the event.  The only time the event will occur is when the server closes the connection.

Comment: @Evk I'm not sure how to solve that. If I use `Thread.Sleep` I'm blocking, just waiting on `ReadAsync` will work but then I can't send a heartbeat to check if the server is still there

Comment: Just use buffer with fixed size and then `await ..ReadAsync(data, 0, buffer.Length);` And you can send a heartbeat, because you can perform write and read operations on network stream at the same time.

Comment: @Evk Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a very robust protocol and permits robust programming. For a client, you don´t need to rely on low level signalling from the network interface, the protocol / language offers all you need (unless your client is so time-critical that it need immediate notification of a network failure):

**Connecting**:

- if connection fails, try again (after a suitable timeout) or give up

**Receiving**:

- set an appropriate receive timeout and act accordingly when the
  timeout exception is thrown (either close the socket and start over
  again or give up, or notify the user or ...). Will "signal" that the server died, or the internet died or ...
- check for bytes received == 0 (indicates a graceful disconnection
  from the other side, FIN) and act accordingly
- if the other side sends a RST, you´ll get an exception, handle that
  accordingly.